# Global exception handling in .NET?

Tags: exception

The whole concept of exception handling is giving me headaches. Currently, what I want to do is to handle specific exceptions that I am positively sure I can handle. On the other hand, I want to terminate the application if an exception that I dont know how to handle is thrown. When I place try-catch blocks in my source code, it looks ugly because there are many of those. Is there a global exception handling mechanism like an event that is fired once an unhandled exception is thrown? That way I can display an error message to the user and terminate the application instead of reiterating this process over and over throughout my source code.

P.S. I want to terminate the application in such a scenario because I am afraid the program might begin functioning improperly once an unhandled exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in C# you can assign a global "unhandled exception handler". To do this, you'd assign a new handler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.

Comment: I see that the event handler kills the process. I want to show a user control and have it terminate the application, but the user control is not shown. The only thing I can display is a message box.

Comment: You could try to invoke a public method on your main window that shows the view, but I'm not sure whether that would work. IIRC there's a flag in the event's parameter that you can use to determine whether the application should quit or not.

Comment: The public method worked only when it had a message box in it. It seems message boxes are special. Also, e.isTerminating is read-only.

Comment: I'd also recommend doing this and logging this exception to some third party service. I work on the following oss project that does this: https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless

Answer (score 3):

In VB.NET you need to handle [My.Application.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a02k5s0(VS.80).aspx) Event:

Example (from MSDN):

```
Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException( _
    ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs _
) Handles Me.UnhandledException
    My.Application.Log.WriteException(e.Exception, _
        TraceEventType.Critical, _
        "Unhandled Exception.")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

are you building a win forms app or a web app?  I wrote a blog entry on a custom [Health Monitor](http://dotnetblogger.com/post/2008/12/03/ASPNET-Health-Monitor.aspx), whereby you can submit exceptions to a database.  Then in the Application_Error method you add code like this.

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)  
    ''# Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs  
    Dim exception As Exception = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError()  
    Dim emailerrors As Boolean = If(LCase(AppSettings.GetAppValue("EmailErrors")) = "yes", True, False)  
    HealthMonitor.Log(exception, emailerrors)  
End Sub
```

What this will do is trap every unhandled error (IE: errors outside your try/catch and log them.  From there (I redirect) you can stop your application, or do whatever you like.

Comment: I am building a WPF application, but I have experience in Win Forms.